# Pass array of objects to next page in IONIC Angular after user clicks button

Tags: angular, ionic3

How can I pass multiple objects containing same `RECEIPT_NUM` and retrieve the objects in next page? Sorry if my question is bad. Newbie to coding

sample JSON

```
putAwayPurchaseOrderListData=[
{
 "Ob1":"35879",
 "0b2":"791314",
 "RECEIPT_NUM":"3396",
 "PO_TYPE":"STD PO"
},
{
 "Ob1":"4995879",
 "0b2":"191314",
 "RECEIPT_NUM":"3396",
 "PO_TYPE":"STD PO"
},
{
 "Ob1":"7995879",
 "0b2":"0491314",
 "RECEIPT_NUM":"1296",
 "PO_TYPE":"STD PO"
}]
```

My Html

```
<ion-card class="item-list-body" *ngFor="let putAwayPurchaseOrder of putAwayPurchaseOrderListData" (click)="goToPutAwayPurchaseOrderDetails(putAwayPurchaseOrder.RECEIPT_NUM,putAwayPurchaseOrderListData)"></ion-card>
```

component1 for sending

```
goToPutAwayPurchaseOrderDetails(RECEIPT_NUM,putAwayPurchaseOrderListData)// sending all objects here. With RECEIPT_NUM thinking to map the objects in next retrieving component
 {
    this.navCtrl.push(PutAwayPurchaseOrderListDetailsPage,{RECEIPT_NUM,putAwayPurchaseOrderListData});

  }
```

component 2 // need to retrieve all the objects containing the clicked card `RECIEPT_NUM`

```
console.log(this.navParams.data)
```

present o/p

```
[3396,{
 "Ob1":"35879",
 "0b2":"791314",
 "RECEIPT_NUM":"3396",
 "PO_TYPE":"STD PO"
},
{
 "Ob1":"4995879",
 "0b2":"191314",
 "RECEIPT_NUM":"3396",
 "PO_TYPE":"STD PO"
},
{
 "Ob1":"7995879",
 "0b2":"0491314",
 "RECEIPT_NUM":"1296",
 "PO_TYPE":"STD PO"
}]
```

expected result only the below objects containing the same `RECEIPT_NUM` objects:

```
{
 "Ob1":"35879",
 "0b2":"791314",
 "RECEIPT_NUM":"3396",
 "PO_TYPE":"STD PO"
},
{
 "Ob1":"4995879",
 "0b2":"191314",
 "RECEIPT_NUM":"3396",
 "PO_TYPE":"STD PO"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a service class. initialize navCtrl in it. and push the data to the variable inside the service class. the variable will be available all classes.
[how to use service, here i am passing a value from app component to sibling component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-alk79g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsibling%2Fsibling.component.html)